# App crashes when clicking hardware-settings-button

Tags: android

I don't have any settings in my app. A friend told me that when pressing the "Settings" button (which I don't see on my emulator btw) the app crashed.

Is there a way to tell Android there are no settings to declare ?

More info : Acer Liquid MT, running Android 2.3.5. See pic (4th button on the right)
[image: Acer picture 4 buttons]

Comment: Please paste your activity code.

Comment: @shree202 added some code

Comment: before doing something make sure which settings button creates problem.. generally default menu does not effect any app.

Comment: Post your logcat then

Comment: Where is this Settings button? Which method handles the onClick? Please add relevant code, without this nobody will be able to help you. Also logcat output would help!

Comment: @donfuxx As I am saying, there is no "settings" button on my app. A friend abroad told me that clicking on the settings button makes the app crash. I don't have access to logcat or anything and I don't know what is this button

Comment: so if your app does not have a settings button... then how your friend clicks non-existent button?

Comment: @donfuxx he told me it is like the menu button for him. his phone has a "settings button" and he can click on it from any app

Comment: There is a physical "settings" button on the phone? Or do you mean a the physical menu button? Which phone is it?

Comment: I have an idea, see answer. I couldn't test it though, because I don't own a device with hardware settings key. But I think it is worth a try ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a device with a hardware settings key, so I could not really test it, but I assume should be possible to handle a hardware settings-key click like this in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SETTINGS) { //ignore settings key         
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
    }
}
```

see here the list of Keycode constants here `KEYCODE_SETTINGS` might be what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SETTINGS

Comment: Did you already had a chance to try this? @Thomas

Comment: I finally got an old phone with a settings key, I tried it and it works fine, thanks ! And thanks for not giving up because I didn't give the code at the beginning, we see that it was not necessary

Comment: Awesome! I also edited the question that it is more clear that it was all about a hardware settings button on a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from your activity. This code is inflating settings menu in your project.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: This is not in my activity.

Comment: Perfect...!!! Absolutely correct...

Comment: @shree202 any other suggestion ? :)

Comment: If this is not in your activity, can you share some code and error log please ? We can't help you without any piece of code

Comment: How does that answer the question? What does that code have to do with the code in the question?

Comment: @Szymon the answer was not a too bad idea, because eclipse usually generates this `onCreateOptionsMenu` standard code when creating a new project. Moreover in the initial version of the question there was no code whatsoever posted, see: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22266828/1

Comment: @donfuxx As it stands, this answer doesn't seem to address the question (the current version) properly. If clarification from the OP is needed, comments should be used for that, not a guess at an answer.

Comment: @Szymon Ok I see your point, but then the question should be closed because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Because guesses are the only possible answers for this as long the code for Settingsbutton is missing.

Comment: @donfuxx Yes, I have already voted to close it.

Comment: welcome to the club :-P @Szymon

Comment: @Szymon Guys its not my first time on SO. Im doing my best to answer your questions. More code won't help, Im saying in my first sentence that there is no settings in my app. The phone in question has a "settings" button

Comment: @Thomas The settings button brings up a menu, I'm guessing. But what you're describing is vague and doesn't allow us to diagnose your problem. We need more information.

Comment: @Szymon finally got it, see edited question